# What happens when the monitored process dies before handle_call is complete?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a question about timing of monitored/linked process dying, and I can't think of how to test it in practice. Here is the scenario I am worried about.

Let's say I have a process called `master` and `slave`.

1. `master` sets `trap_exit` to `true`.
2. `master` does `{ok, Pid} = slave:start_link()` thus linking the two.
3. `master` does the equivalent of `gen_server:call(Pid, Msg)`.
4. *Before* the message arrives at `Pid` that process crashes.

Question:

1. Will `master` receive an `EXIT` message first? or
2. Will `master` fail with `{noproc,{gen_server..` exception since `Pid` is already dead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a proofed answer but here is what might happen.

First thing we should understand is that `EXIT` is a message that is being sent to the `master`s mailbox. In contrast to the `noproc` error, which is an error that is being generated within the `master` process context (not a message).
This means that you will probably get both. The question is who will come first.

Since the `EXIT` message is being sent immediately and since you said that the process crashes before the `call` arrived, it makes sense that you will first get the `EXIT` message. Although, since they are independent, there is an option that before the `EXIT` message arrives to the `master`s mailbox, your `gen_server:call` will return with a `noproc` error.

In case you are asking this for your implementation purpose, I would suggest covering both cases. I really don't think that Erlang promises which one will be first.